# How to download playlist from Youtube?

Tags: downloads, youtube, mp3

I need to download a Youtube playlist as mp3 audio. What is the most convenient way to do this on Ubuntu?
I tried:

```
youtube-dl --ignore-errors --format bestaudio --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 160K --output "%(title)s.%(ext)s" --yes-playlist ...
```

It didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try to Update "youtube-dl"  using:

```
sudo youtube-dl -U
```

Sometime, under Linux the URL can cause problem, so you can only use the "ID", not the complete URL

like :

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_FTuCckY34&list=RDCLAK5uy_kT4N8v_Q_Q3eFXmkdTMUWDlVlgrnLnmxE&start_radio=1
```

Playlist ID is: RDCLAK5uy_kT4N8v_Q_Q3eFXmkdTMUWDlVlgrnLnmxE

Video ID is: n_FTuCckY34

Comment: I get:    youtube-dl: error: youtube-dl's self-update mechanism is disabled on Debian.
Please update youtube-dl using apt(8).

Comment: try this:  sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
and:
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

Comment: you can save it elsewhere then "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl"  (in your home...)

Comment: Thank you! Now it works, but it looks like it only downloads the first song.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good video downloader ([4K Download](https://www.4kdownload.com/)) that lets you download videos from various platforms with YouTube being one of their renowned targets. It equally has an option to download a playlist.

---

**Note:** I'm not affiliated, and can't also list steps of a solution here.
The best thing I'll tell you to do is to visit the above-mentioned link (*"hopefully no link issues come up one-day"*), and enjoy!

Answer (score -2):

Previously, if there is a desire or need to download audio, you should engage the appropriate knowledge. Nowadays, a lot of knowledge is not required for such actions; click on the download button at [mp3search](https://mp3search.fm/).FM, and that's it. Your music is installed on your hard drive. After that, you will be able to share your music or listen to it yourself without any difficulties. I mostly use it for working out (running on the street) or on the road. Usually, my friends and I play the downloaded songs if we don't have mobile internet.